# Field Calculator Python Issues

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy

How can I adapt the following expression in the ArcGIS field calculator? Below is the python code:

```
import arcpy
fc = "2014_2"
keyField = "ID_segment"
affectedField = "KKN2"
maxVal = 2500
cnt = 1
Value = -1
oldValue = str(maxVal)
queryString = '"' + keyField + '" < ' + "" + oldValue + ""
rows2 = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc, queryString)
row2 = rows2.next()
while row2:
        iValue = row2.getValue("ID_segment")
        if iValue != Value :
                cnt = 1
                Value = iValue
        else :
                cnt = cnt + 1
        kVal = str(row2.getValue("KKN")) + "/" + str(cnt)   
        print(Value,kVal)
        row2.setValue(affectedField, kVal)
        rows2.updateRow(row2)
        row2 = rows2.next()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you give an example and tell us what you are trying to accomplish? Either way, anything that is related to the *UpdateCursor* can be omitted when using the Field Calculator. You would also put your code into a *function*, so it can be called on each entry in your table.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my qusetions. Could you look at the question

Comment: Essentially, you are asking the community to do the work for you.  This forum works best if you first make an attempt and then post a question where you are stuck or have a more specific question.

Comment: Still not sure what you are trying to accomplish. You are comparing whether your *keyField* is smaller than *oldValue*, is that right? And then? Can you maybe add an example to your question?

Comment: explain what the python code does. and what you want the field calculator to do. (in your original question please)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples of [field calculator expressions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/00170000004s000000/). This will show you what the different parts of the field calculator are for.  As BritishSteel suggested, you won't need the updateCursor since the field calculator already does this.

I'd suggest starting with the outlining the processes in the script at each step so that you know what it is trying to accomplish. A chunk of your existing python code is for iterating through the rows so you can remove that.

Once you have an outline, you can figure out how to write those steps in to the field calculator.